# How to fix `packets larger than config size` error when using `pymysql`

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm using `pymysql` to connect a MySQL server to do somet work. Here is my code

```
import pymysql

mysql_info = {"host":"127.0.0.1", "port":3306, "user":"root", "password":"123"}
conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_info)
cr = conn.cursor()
cr.execute("select count(distinct my_field) from my_db.my_table")
```

And it raises an error:

> pymysql.err.InternalError:(9002, 'MySQLNormalMergeNode receive packets larger than config size')

The total length of `my_db.my_table` is just 120,000 and each element of `my_field` likes `71002030000100BM`. I have tried to set `max_allowed_packed` to 512M but it seems doesn't work. And I can execute the same SQL in Navicat successfully.

I am really want to know why. By the way, my goal is to find the number of `my_field` after duplicates are removed and I can't be more thankful if someone could offer my another way to achieve that.